# "Where" Linq capability in my own application

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I need to have "Where" Linq functionality in my own code.

Let me explain: we have an application that lets users write the so-called "user code", which is code in C# that will be picked up by the app and compiled and run at runtime.

In user code, I need to be able to specify an SQL condition. A special case is the condition on a date column. We may have conditions like **[DateColumn] = '1/1/2001'** which are easy to implement, but also **[DateColumn] = GetDate() + 1**. In the latter case I would need to implement an parser to "understand" the expression. I don't want to blindly send to SQL whatever the user enters (avoid *SQL injection*).

The user would be most pleased to write a Linq-like query like this:

```
xxx.Where(field => field == new DateTime(2001, 1, 1));
xxx.Where(field => field == DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
```

Is it possible to leverage the Linq to SQL framework in any way? I would need the SQL generated in the back to further construct the whole query and send it to SQL Server.

Are there any 3rd party tools that may help me?

I don't require the whole IQueryable interfaces (to compose, join querys etc.). Only the ability to convert a System.Linq.Expressions.Expression to T-SQL (even with limitations).

What is the System.Linq.* namespace that exposes this conversion functionality for SQL? Maybe I can get a few hints with Reflector.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The following library looks promising: http://www.codeplex.com/IQToolkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Sample code in the SDK called dynamic linq.

\CS 2008 Samples\LinqSamples\DynamicQuery

You can do such things:

```
Northwind db = new Northwind(connString); 
db.Log = Console.Out;

var query =
    db.Customers.Where("City == @0 and Orders.Count >= @1", "London", 10).
    OrderBy("CompanyName").
    Select("New(CompanyName as Name, Phone)");
```

Another possibility is to implement a Custom Linq Provider. A very good example can be found at "THE WAYWARD WEBLOG" http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/pages/linq-links.aspx. This Blog helped me implementing my own custom Provider.

```
public interface IQueryable : IEnumerable {       
    Type ElementType { get; }
    Expression Expression { get; }
    IQueryProvider Provider { get; }
}

public interface IQueryProvider {
    IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression);
    IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression);
    object Execute(Expression expression);
    TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, not really what I need. I just need a quick way to convert an Expression => T-SQL string.

Comment: Well, maybe you'll need to write a Custom Linq Proivder. Here are some very good blogpost about it. I used them too for my custom linq provider. http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/pages/linq-links.aspx

Comment: Yes, I'm beginning to think it's the only way. Unfortunately I don't have experience with writing the provider, that's why I was hoping for some 3rd party code. :D

Comment: Arthur, if you want, rewrite your comment about IQToolkit and the "THE WAYWARD WEBLOG" as an answer and I'll flag it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you can make use of Linq's lazy evaluation to acheive this. If I understand your question correctly, I think you can do something like this;

```
// Before user code:
var products = from p in db.products select p;

// Insert user-generated code here, such as i.e.
userProducts = products.Where(p => price < 1000);

// After user code:
for (var product in userProducts)
{
  Whatever(product);
}
```

Since linq is lazy, the actual SQL query will not be issued to the database before you enumerate the 'result', in this case, "userProducts".

Comment: Actually, I don't need anything other than the conversion mechanism from Expression to string (T-SQL).

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect, I think you're jumping out of the frying pan and into the fire. You don't want to permit SQL injection, but you're permitting *code* injection. C# code, even a lambda, allows side effects.

AFAIK, C# 4.0 does allow you to dynamically compile code. But you'll have to perform compiler-quality analysis to prevent the user from doing something stupid or malicious. It's *much* simpler to massage the WHERE clause to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: The application that I'm talking about is a large one, that has several layers of security enforcement, to make sure it doesn't behave in a malicious way. The code is run in a sandbox, only a very small group of people (administrators) have access to writing user code etc. So the "code injection" is by design.

It's not relevant "why" I need this functionality and all the possible security implications, but my question was "how" to do it. I'm aware that I can create my own QueryProvider for this purpose, but I was looking for the easies, most tested way of doing it.

Comment: ... Actually the SQL injection is not an issue. I can pretty much trust the users to not write 'drop table' commands, but it's more about not "tempting" them to mess around with the underlying implementation of the system (writing SQL code). It is about providing simple API for creating powerfull filters.

Comment: I understand. Regardless, I don't think you should expose either SQL or C# directly to the users. Ones you've put some abstract (UI) layer between the users and the data, it's an implementation detail whether you translate that abstraction to SQL or C#. In the latter case, I believe .NET exposes the compiler, either in 4.0 or 3. something.